# Find the equation of the line.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Find the equation of the line passing through the point $(5,7)$ and parallel to the line $5x+4=0$

If I say $m=5$, how should I find $c$? There is no $y$ in the equation!

Comment: $5x+4=0$ means $x$ is constant: hence your slope is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slope of $5$ is wrong. $5x+4=0\implies x=-\frac{4}{5}$. Constant $x$ means that the line is perpendicular to the $x$-axis. Any line parallel to this, will also be perpendicular to the $x$-axis, implying that it will have constant $x$.

Finally we already know the value of that $x$, since a point lying on the line, $(5,7)$ is known. Thus the required equation of line is $x=5$

Comment: at the end, how do we substitute the values of $m, x, y$ in $y=mx+c$?

Comment: @Kiara in this case you can't. Since the original equation was $5x+0y+4=0$, which would lead to $m=\frac{5}{0}$ which is undefined.

Comment: sorry for troubling, but then how do we get the equation of the line without the formula?

Comment: @Kiara read my answer. at which specific sentence did you lose me?

Comment: "Finally we already know the value of that x, since a point lying on the line, (5,7) is known. Thus the required equation of line is x=5"

Comment: I got it that $m = \frac{-4}{5}$ but what after that? How to use those coordinates?

Comment: @Kiara $x=-\frac45$ not $m$.

Comment: Which means $x$ is **constant**. that is for any value of $y$, $x$ remains the same.

Comment: @Kiara Now, for constant $x$, the line will be vertical, do you understand that?

Comment: I've been reading your answer since last night, now I got it! thanks...tried drawing graphs :)